useNavigate() isn't working in my Remix Shopify app
I'm building a Shopify Remix app and am having trouble getting navigation to work when using the useNavigate() Remix hook. I have two Polaris components attempting to use the hook in the code below (the EmptyState and Page components) and when I click their respective buttons in the UI, nothing happens. I've tried adding console.logs within the onAction functions and nothing is showing up in the console either when I click. Does anyone have any ideas?
import {
  Card,
  Layout,
  Page,
  Text,
  IndexTable,
  Thumbnail,
  useIndexResourceState,
  Badge,
  EmptyState,
} from "@shopify/polaris";
import { useLoaderData, useNavigate, Link } from "@remix-run/react";
import { json } from "@remix-run/node";
import { authenticate } from "~/shopify.server";
import { DeleteIcon } from "@shopify/polaris-icons";
import { QUERY_PAGES } from "~/graphql/queries/AdminQueries";
import { request as graphqlRequest } from "graphql-request"
import dayjs from "dayjs";
import utc from "dayjs/plugin/utc";
dayjs.extend(utc);

export async function loader({ request }) {
  await authenticate.admin(request);
  const response = await graphqlRequest(process.env.APP_GRAPHQL_URI, QUERY_PAGES);
  const pageLayouts = response.GetPages;

  return json({ pageLayouts });
}

export default function Pages() {

  const { pageLayouts } = useLoaderData();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  function getBadgeTone(status: String) {
    switch (status) {
      case 'Active':
        return 'success';
      case 'Expired':
        return 'critical';
      case 'Disabled':
        return 'default';
      case 'Draft':
        return 'attention'
      default:
        return 'default';
    }
  }

  const resourceName = {
    singular: 'pageLayout',
    plural: 'pageLayouts',
  };

  const {selectedResources, allResourcesSelected, handleSelectionChange} =
    useIndexResourceState(pageLayouts);

  const rowMarkup = pageLayouts.map(
    (
      {internalId, preview, name, keywords, isDated, category, createdAt, updatedAt, status},
      index,
    ) => (
      <IndexTable.Row
        id={internalId}
        key={internalId}
        selected={selectedResources.includes(internalId)}
        position={index}
      >
        <IndexTable.Cell>
          <Text variant="bodyMd" fontWeight="bold" as="span">
            {internalId}
          </Text>
        </IndexTable.Cell>
        <IndexTable.Cell><Thumbnail source={preview} alt="thumbnail"/></IndexTable.Cell>
        <IndexTable.Cell><Link to="url">{name}</Link></IndexTable.Cell>
        <IndexTable.Cell>{keywords.join(', ')}</IndexTable.Cell>
        <IndexTable.Cell>{isDated ? "Dated" : "Undated"}</IndexTable.Cell>
        <IndexTable.Cell>{category.name}</IndexTable.Cell>
        <IndexTable.Cell><Badge tone={getBadgeTone(status)}>{status}</Badge></IndexTable.Cell>
        <IndexTable.Cell>{dayjs(createdAt).format('DD/MM/YY h:mmA')}</IndexTable.Cell>
        <IndexTable.Cell>{dayjs(updatedAt).format('DD/MM/YY h:mmA')}</IndexTable.Cell>
      </IndexTable.Row>
    ),
  );

  const promotedBulkActions = [
    {
      icon: DeleteIcon,
      destructive: true,
      content: 'Delete pages',
      onAction: () => console.log('Todo: implement deleting customers'),
    },
  ];


  const EmptyLayoutState = () => (
    <EmptyState
      heading="Add page layouts for customisable planners."
      action={{
        content: "Add Layout",
        onAction: () => {
          console.log("Navigate to new page");
          navigate('/app/pages/new')
        }
      }}
      image="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0262/4071/2726/files/emptystate-files.png"
    >
    </EmptyState>
  );

  return (
    <Page
    fullWidth={true}
    title="Page Layouts"
    subtitle="test subtitle"
    primaryAction={{
      content: 'Add Layout',
      onAction: () => {
        console.log("Navigate to new page");
        navigate('/app/pages/new')
      }
      }
    }
    >
      <Layout>
        <Layout.Section>
          <Card>
            {pageLayouts.length === 0 ? (
              <EmptyLayoutState/>
            ) : (
              <IndexTable
              resourceName={resourceName}
              itemCount={pageLayouts.length}
              selectedItemsCount={
                allResourcesSelected ? 'All' : selectedResources.length
              }
              promotedBulkActions={promotedBulkActions}
              onSelectionChange={handleSelectionChange}
              headings={[
                {title: 'ID'},
                {title: 'Preview'},
                {title: 'Page name'},
                {title: 'Keywords'},
                {title: 'Dated / Undated'},
                {title: 'Category'},
                {title: 'Status'},
                {title: 'Date Added'},
                {title: 'Date Modified'},
              ]}>
              {rowMarkup}
            </IndexTable>
            )}
          </Card>
        </Layout.Section>
      </Layout>
    </Page>
  );
}



https://polaris.shopify.com/components/layout-and-structure/page?example=page-with-custom-primary-action your primary action content looks quite different to the documentation

I'm also facing the same issue, in my case console appears but page doesn't navigate, it fails, and i can see hydration errors in console. But when i navigate that page directly (by pasting url in browser), it works fine.
